# Script ou comando para somar todos os diretórios e mostrar o tamanho total

Tags: linux, script, shell

Estou desenvolvendo um script onde a partir de uma lista de texto onde terá o nome dos diretórios, o script pegar o nome de cada diretório, mostrar o tamanho de cada diretório e depois o total.

Exemplo:

Preciso somar o tamanho total de algumas contas no servidor, digamos que eu tenho os seguintes diretórios:

```
/home/conta1
/home/conta2
/home/conta3
/home/conta4
/home/conta5
/home/conta6
```

Por questão de um filtro, eu irie criar um arquivo de texto com o nome `lista.txt` e nele irei colocar o nome dos diretórios que eu desejo mostrar o tamanho individual depois a soma de todos:

```
cat lista.txt
conta2
conta4
```

Digamos que eu deseje o tamanho dos diretórios acima, eu tentei fazer um `for`, mas não deu certo:

```
for i in $(cat lista.txt); do du -hcs /home/$i;done
```

O resultado dele sai assim, mostrando cada conta e o total em baixo.

```
684K    /home/conta2
684K    total
732K    /home/conta4
732K    total
1,1M    /home/conta5
1,1M    total
```

Para que apareça da maneira que eu desejo, tem que rodar o comando assim:

```
du -shc /home/conta1 /home/conta2 /home/conta3
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer o script pegar o nome de cada diretório, somar a quantidade de diretórios, jogar em uma variável cada nome e em seguida executar assim:

```
du -shc /home/$1 /home/$2 /home/$3
```

Answer (score 2):

Faça assim:

```
for i in $(cat lista.txt); do pastas="$i $pastas";done; du -hcs $pastas
```

Explicação:

no loop, cria-se uma variável chamada *pastas* que é a concatenção (com espaço) dos diretórios contidos em lista.txt

Após terminar o loop, executa-se o comando *du*, passando como parametro a variável *pastas*.

Answer (score 2):

```
du -hcs $(sed 's!^!/home/!' lista.txt)
```